# Weight Conversion - How to combine various Print Methods into 1 Print Method

Tags: java

I am a novice programmer who is learning Java and though my homework is complete I want to make it neater. I wanted to know if I can combine the following print methods into one and at least combine Kilograms to Pounds and Pounds to Kilograms Methods into one.

**Note, I can't use anything more advanced then if statements and loops.**

Because this is my first time posting and I want to make sure I provide all answerers with adequate information I have uploaded my Weight Conversion java file to here: [Weight Conversion Java file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjphxsi87nxiexj/WeightConversion.java).

Any other advice as to how to simplify the code, or following better code etiquette is welcomed too.

Here are the print statements:

```
/**
* This method below prints the calculations calculateKG and calculateLBS
*/
public static void printRESULTS1( double dResult1, double dResult2){
// Prints the result of Pounds to Kilograms 
System.out.print(dResult1 + " pounds is " + dResult2 + " kilograms.");
}// end method printRESULTS1

/**
* This method below prints the calculations calculateKG and calculateLBS
*/
public static void printRESULTS2( double dResult1, double dResult2){
// Prints the result of Pounds to Kilograms 
System.out.print( dResult1 + " kilograms is " + dResult2 + " pounds");
}// end method printRESULTS2

/**
* This method below prints the calculations calculateOZ and calculateLBS
*/ 
public static void printRESULTS3( double dResultOZ, double dResultLBS){
// Prints the result of Pounds to Kilograms 
System.out.print( dResultOZ + " ounces is " + dResultLBS + " pounds");
}// end method printRESULTS3 

/**
* This method below prints the calculations calculateOZ and calculateLBS
*/ 
public static void printRESULTS4( double dResultLBS, double dResultOZ){
// Prints the result of Pounds to Kilograms 
System.out.print( dResultLBS + " pounds is " + dResultOZ + " ounces ");
}// end method printRESULTS4
```

Comment: +1 for providing well-commented, well-formatted source code at your first question. Anyway, you should copy the relevant bits into your question, so that it becomes clear what you are asking.

Comment: Are you allowed to use polymorphism or it is too advanced? It may be an alternative to simplify your code.

Comment: Hi Trein, Thank you for the quick response! No unfortunately that wasn't anything we have covered so far.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, consider this:

```
public static void printResults(
    double dResultFrom,
    String from,
    double dResultTo,
    String to)
{
    System.out.print(dResultFrom + " " + from + " is " + dResultTo + " " + to);
}
```

Not sure about the whole context you're using it and about your limitations. Of course further refactoring steps are possible. For example:

```
public static void printResults(
    double resultFrom,
    String fromDescription,
    double resultTo,
    String toDescription)
{
    String formattedResult = formatResult(
        resultFrom,
        fromDescription,
        resultTo,
        toDescription);

    System.out.print(formattedResult);
}

public static String formatResult(
    double resultFrom,
    String fromDescription,
    double resultTo,
    String toDescription)
{
    return formatQuantity(resultFrom, fromDescription)
        + " is "
        + formatQuantity(resultTo, toDescription);
}

public static String formatQuantity(double value, String description)
{
    return value + " " + description;
}
```

Note much less code duplication than in your example, and a clear separation of responsibilities (formatting functions, and printing function). For example, if you had to print results to a file, not to the console, this design would prove more flexible.

Comment: Hey BartoszKP thank you for the response, I don't understand really why the distinction between Format and Print results. And I guess your solution is too abstract for me to understand at this point.

Comment: @user1409175 Your print function does two things: it generates proper strings with content - that's formatting, and outputs it to the screen - that's printing. This is doing "two things". Consider my example, if you wanted to print results to a file - you couldn't use your functions, as they always print to console. But you could use formatting functions presented here (they return a string with appropriate content), and then do whatever you wish with the string. Transmit it over a network, write to file, display in a window, or print out to the console.

Comment: Consider also the code duplication problem - this might be easier to grasp. What if you wanted to change the way things are being printed to the console? For example - change the language? In my example - you modify only one place in the code. In your snippet, much more places need to be altered.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, it made me think harder as to how to simplify the code and organize it better. Also great advice on making sure that the code could be universal as in the print method could be used in another language that isn't English. What really helped was understanding that I can have more then 2 parameters in a Method.

```
    public static void printRESULTS(int nConversion, double dResult1, double dResult2){
    //Declare variable
    String output = "";

    //Pounds to Kilogram output
    if (nConversion == 1){
       output = dResult1 + " pounds is " + dResult2 + " kilograms.";
       System.out.println(output);
    }
    //Kilograms to Pounds output
    else if (nConversion == 2){
       output = dResult1 + " kilograms is " + dResult2 + " pounds. ";
       System.out.println(output);
    }
    //Ounces to Pounds output
    else if (nConversion == 3){
       output = dResult1 + " ounces is " + dResult2 + " pounds. ";
       System.out.println(output);
    }
    //Pounds to Ounces output
    else if (nConversion == 4){
       output = dResult1 + " pounds is " + dResult2 + " ounces. ";
       System.out.println(output);
    }
```